# .war file created using ZipOutputStream fails to deploy

Tags: java, xml, weblogic-10.x, zipinputstream, zipoutputstream

I am reading a .war file and after reading it into a ZipInputStream , i edit the web.xml and add weblogic.xml - and then transfer all this into ZipOutputStream , which i write as the final output.war file.

The problem that i am facing is , the output.war is not deployable in WLS . Its not giving any errors. it is showing that the web app is active , but on access i get ERROR 403.

But if i open the .war file using any archiver  say winzip , edit the web.xml and weblogic.xml , then i am able to deploy .(By edit i mean , just delete a space somewere and save again - no changes) .

Any idea why this could be happening ? Edit and saving the xmls , would prob change the FORMAT or ENCODING tye ? is that the reason ?

(usig weblogic 10.3.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can *read* JARs using a `ZipInputStream`, you can't *write* them with a `ZipOutputStream`. You need to use a `JarOutputStream`, otherwise what you create won't be a JAR, it'll be a ZIP, and it won't deploy.

JARs are ZIPs with some extra meta-data, so they can be read as ZIPs, but need to be created with a special tool.

Comment: I initially tried with JarOutputStream. Later i just gave a shot with ZipOutputStream . But sadly both gave the same results.

Comment: stupid mistakes from my side i say .. somewere along the code , instead if using file.separator i hard coded '/' . in linux is caused issues.